# Import functions and structures from other files in GO?

Tags: go, web

I am new to GO, just started trying to build a webserver to learn some basics.
My `main.go` file is becoming quite bloated so I wanted to move some functions and structures outside of the main file into files like `structures.go` and `utilities.go`.

When I do that in GoLand, it seems like it automatically detects them and I don't get any immediate errors. However when I execute `go run main.go` I get errors saying that my route functions are undefined.

Here's what my directory looks like

```
-MyProject
--main.go
--routes.go
--structures.go
--go.mod
```

Here's what's inside my `go.mod` file

```
module <github_username>/<github_repo>

go 1.16

require github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0
```

Here's the current beginning of the `main.go` file

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)
```

I have also tried adding "routes" and "structures" into the `import` block but I get the error `Cannot resolve file <filename>`

I am not very clear on how Go locates packages, but perhaps this is important that my project is not located in `~/User/<user>/go/src`. From what I understood with the introduction of module mode in Go you don't have to have your project there, but I might be completely wrong about that.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Edit.

All the functions inside of `routes.go` are named using capital letters since I saw a SO post that mentioned you need that to be able to import things from other files.

Comment: The files routes.go and structures.go are in the same package as main.go.  Reference the symbols in those files directly. For example if routes.go has `func Hello() { fmt.Print("Hello") }`, then main.go can call it with `Hello()`.  If you need more assistance, edit the question to show the contents of main.go, routes.go and structures.go.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I created a function Greet to test it out nad for some reason I am getting an error saying ./main.go:22:2: undefined: Greet

Comment: You are probably executing `go run main.go` instead of using `go build` or `go install`.  The tutorial [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code) is a good introduction to building a basic program.

Comment: Do not use file name arguments for building packages. Nowhere in the documentation does it say to do that. Just run `go build` and go back to “How to Write Go Code” for reference

Comment: Ok, doing things the `go build` and `go install` way worked, I guess I misinterpreted what `go run` does since I thought it was still compiling the code in `main.go` but to a temporary folder. I don't know why the downvotes, but thank you for the suggestions in any case.

Comment: Ah, that's fair, I didn't want to flood the question with code but now that you mention it I could have included at least some samples. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import anything.

routes.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Routes() { // Capitalize function name to use it outside this file
  fmt.Println("Hello routes!")
}
```

main.go

```
package main

func main() {
  Routes() // Hello routes!
}
```

---

If you have the package i.e. file inside a folder, then you may call the function with that package name. Example: `routes.Routes()`. Where routes is a package (folder). In this case, you have to import `import "<module that is defined in go.mod>/routes`. Notice to use lowercase letters for your folders.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that makes sense, and after following the suggestions in the comments above I tried using `go build` and `go install` and things worked.